# Acessing my future in the Futurebuilder in Flutter/dart doesn't work

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm dumb and don't understand anything anymore. I'm trying to get my JSON Data and show it in my app, I linked all relevant code snippets below, this is my first post so I'm sorry if I need to add anything else.
I simply have 2 problems. 1. I dont know how to access the data in my FutureBuilder from my AnalystModel, I tried different ways, for example using a FutureBuilder and accessing my data by using snapshot.hasdata[index]['analystCount'], everything had it's own problems, please help. I also use a new version of flutter so 'snapshot.data!analystCount won't work.
My 2nd problem is the Error I've added below, trying to add the <List> to my FutureBuilder, the solution in the internet I found to this error simply was ,,use a FutureBuilder" but i already do:

```
class Analysts {

  final String analystCount;
  final String consensusDate;
  final String marketConsensus;
  final String marketConsensusTargetPrice;

  Analysts({this.analystCount, this.consensusDate, this.marketConsensus,
    this.marketConsensusTargetPrice,});

  factory Analysts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Analysts(
      analystCount: json['analystCount'].toString() as String,
      consensusDate: json['consensusDate'] as String,
      marketConsensus: json['marketConsensus'].toString() as String,
      marketConsensusTargetPrice: json['marketConsensusTargetPrice'].toString() as String,
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Cloudservice:

```
class IEXCloudServiceAnalysts {

  Future<List<Analysts>> getData() async{

    var url = Uri.parse("https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/time-series/CORE_ESTIMATES/TSLA?token=Tpk_85b3b5cdb32147d3a0fb751cc5176cdd");
    Response res = await get(url);

    return parseAnalysis(res.body);

  }
}

List<Analysts> parseAnalysis(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<Analysts>((json) => Analysts.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

This is my endpoint for the text:

```
FutureBuilder<Analysts>(
                      future: iexcloudanalysts.getData(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          Analysts analysts = Analysts();
                          return Text(
                            analysts.consensusDate ?? 'Error',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 32,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        if(snapshot.hasError){
                          return Text(
                            'N/A',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 32,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        else {
                          return const Text(
                            "---",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 32,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      }
                  ),
```

The Error I get:

```
lib/Widgets/stock_analysts_widget.dart:63:48: Error: The argument type 'Future<List<Analysts>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Analysts>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Analysts' is from 'package:flutter_app/models/analysts.dart' ('lib/models/analysts.dart').
                      future: iexcloudanalysts.getData(),
                                               ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct future builder generic type
`FutureBuilder<List<Analysts>>`

Comment: This solved my first problem, however, I still can't access the data in Analysts I got. 'analyst.consensusDate only returns a Null value.

Comment: use `snapshot.data` to get  `List<Analysts>` returned from `iexcloudanalysts.getData()`

Comment: I want to be able to show the data from my link, the JSON information, for example, the analystCount. This doesn't work it will only return '[Instance of Analysts]'

Comment: `snapshot.data![0]?. analystCount` To use the first element